# Finding the linear fractional transformation which involves infinity

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that we use the following when we try to find a linear fractional transformation,
$\frac { \left( w - w _ { 1 } \right) \left( w _ { 2 } - w _ { 3 } \right) } { \left( w - w _ { 3 } \right) \left( w _ { 2 } - w _ { 1 } \right) } = \frac { \left( , z - z _ { 1 } \right) \left( z _ { 2 } - z _ { 3 } \right) } { \left( z - z _ { 3 } \right) \left( z _ { 2 } - z _ { 1 } \right) }$
However, trying to solve the following question, I need to deal with infinity.

$$\Psi ( 1 ) = i , \Psi ( 0 ) = \infty , \Psi ( - 1 ) = 1$$
$$\Psi ( 2 ) = 1 , \Psi ( i ) = i , \Psi ( \infty ) = - 3 i$$

Is there any shortcut for finding unique linear fractional transformations of these types?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Psi(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$,

**For First row:**
$$\Psi(0) = \infty \Longrightarrow d=0 \Longrightarrow c \neq 0 \ \text{ You can Suppose } \ c=1$$
Now you remain $2$ equations with $2$ variables that simply can be solved.

**For Second row:**
$$\Psi(\infty) = -3i \Longrightarrow \frac{a}{c}=-3i \qquad \text{ You Can Suppose } \qquad a=-3i \quad \& \quad c=1$$
Now you remain $2$ equations with $2$ variables that simply can be solved.